# Using CTRL + C to kill localhost, but command line then becomes unresponsive

Tags: localhost, iterm2

Using iTerm2 on my Macbook Pro, when I kill localhost with `CTRL + C`, the terminal becomes unresponsive and I am left on a blank line unable to do anything. On my older laptop, it would direct me back to the directory I was on.

The photo showcases:

- localhost running
- `CTRL + C`
- `^Cmake: *** [Makefile:64: run_dev_build_container] Interrupt line` shows and kills localhost
- Unresponsive terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
control + \
```

This command will kill localhost and direct you back to your root folder in your terminal.